# In Azure devops, how to query task that was not close in the same day it was activated/ when the state was changed?

Tags: azure-devops

Im a bit new at azure devops and I am trying to view task that was not close in the same day it was activated/ when its state was changed using query. My point of confusion is that I dont know how compare the state change date with the close date.

[image: My attempt]

the output should be tasks that are still active and task that are closed but not in the same date it state was change

UPDATE

So I was wondering if my approach was wrong so I tried different approach.

[image: My second attempt]

here I try using the `[]<>` to compare completed date with activation date, it should have sorted to show only task that the activation date are different from the close date but here I still got shown tasks which have close date and activation date in the same date.

UPDATE 2
Since I cant use the '[]<>', I decided to use the not so smart way to compare the task close date, active date, and create date as seen in the screenshot below, it is ugly but it works. If anyone knows a smarter way to do this, please do tell.

[My current solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moXLK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I still got shown tasks which have close date and activation date in the same date.*

The reason for this problem you met is that when you use the condition “Closed Date <>[Field] Activated Date”, the values of these two fields are actually datetime format which means it contains hours, minutes and seconds like below:

[image]

That’s why you can still see the records shown with same date.

As for the requirement you mentioned, there’s no directly available solution you can use in Azure DevOps Query as far as I know.

In addition, please refer to [Group clauses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#group-clauses) where you can see how to set conditions for “not close in the same day it was activated/ when its state was changed”, like below:

[image]

Comment: how to view the date time format just like you did? Is it by using wiql?Also is it posible to actually do something like 
Closed Date <>[Field] Activated Date + 1?

Comment: 1.The way i get the detail information of my work item is called Resr API, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 for more information.
2.It's not wiql.
3.It's not possible. As you can see, the operater is <>[Field] which needs a field name, like [Activated Date], which can't be used as a mathematical operation.You can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-operators-variables?view=azure-devops#query-operators